# Testing flux with StepVerifier

Tags: java, project-reactor

I am learning `Reactive Programming` from that page: [tutorial](https://tech.io/playgrounds/929/reactive-programming-with-reactor-3/Request). And I am wondering why in the below example stact trace throws error with actual one record when I expect 4?

```
java.lang.AssertionError: expectation "expectNextCount(4)" failed (expected: count = 4; actual: counted = 1; signal: onComplete())

// TODO Create a StepVerifier that initially requests all values and expect 4 values to be received
StepVerifier requestAllExpectFour(Flux<User> flux) {
        return StepVerifier.withVirtualTime(() -> Flux.just(flux))
                .expectSubscription()
                .thenRequest(4)
                .expectNextCount(4)
                .expectComplete();
}
```

I'm wondering if I'm missing something here.

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
StepVerifier requestAllExpectFour(Flux<User> flux) {
    return StepVerifier.withVirtualTime(() -> flux)
            .expectSubscription() 
            .thenRequest(Long.MAX_VALUE) 
            .expectNextCount(4) 
            .expectComplete(); 
}
```

or like this

```
StepVerifier requestAllExpectFour(Flux<User> flux) {
    return StepVerifier.create(flux)
            .expectSubscription() 
            .thenRequest(Long.MAX_VALUE) 
            .expectNextCount(4) 
            .expectComplete(); 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think the problem is you're supplying a flux with a single emission of flux, by using Flux.just. You could just apply the flux itself:

```
.withVirtualTime(() -> flux)
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining the issue - opposed to just posting a "solution" like in the other answers.

Answer (score 0):

source code -> https://github.com/reactor/lite-rx-api-hands-on

issue -> https://github.com/reactor/reactor-addons/issues/61

guide -> https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#_manipulating_time

and code below works...

```
StepVerifier requestAllExpectFour(Flux<User> flux) {
    List<User> users = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(User.SKYLER, User.JESSE, User.WALTER, User.SAUL));
    return StepVerifier.withVirtualTime(() -> 
                Flux.interval(Duration.ofMillis(100))
                   .zipWith(Flux.fromIterable(users), (i, user) -> user))
            .expectSubscription()  
            .thenRequest(4) 
            .thenAwait(Duration.ofMillis(400))
            .expectNextCount(4)  
        .expectComplete();  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess that what the exercise wants is that you initialize the StepVerifier **with the request** using the constructor, like this:

```
StepVerifier requestAllExpectFour(Flux<User> flux) {
    return StepVerifier.create(flux, 4)
          .expectNextCount(4)
          .expectComplete();
}
```